# Part of JavaScript file doesn't execute if I run firebase serve

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My issue is quite simple. I am somewhat learning firebase particularly cloud functions. When I run firebase serve, it doesnt execute parts of my js fle. Any new code I insert into the js file, will not be added. When I checked sources, I found only half the script. However, if I use vs code live server to serve up the files, the full script will be run. But live server is not ideal because I am using the automatic method to connect to firebase and not the cdn, so live server cannot connect to the firebase libraries

```
const requestModal = document.querySelector('.new-request');
const requestBtn = document.querySelector('.add-request');

requestBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  requestModal.classList.add('open');
});
requestModal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('new-request')){
      requestModal.classList.remove('open');
  }else{
      alert('This is a modal, click on the outside to close it.');
      alert('Modal Closed');
  }
});

// say hello function call
const button = document.querySelector('.callBtn');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('What are you');
  // get function reference
  const sayHello = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sayHello');
  sayHello().then(result => {
      console.log(result.data);
  });
});
```

This last button is where the problem is. The button ref and the event listener is not being added to the script file when I run it through  firebase serve.
I tried using console.log() from the html directly, it worked but if I use firebase serve, I experience that problem.

Comment: Can you explain what specifically is not working ?

Comment: Like I said, if I run firebase serve in order to serve the project to a development server, the button ('.callBtn') and its event handler doesn't work. I inspected the code on the browser and went to sources, what I found is that all that part of the js file is missing.

Comment: Are you sure that the code is actually uploaded?

Comment: like I said, the problem seems to be from setting up a development server using "firebase serve". I say this because I used vs code's live server to serve it up and the js worked fine. With "firebase serve", part of the js is missing after it is served.